# Why does Spring boot does partiality when processing @Bean annotation for void function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 function in my Configuration class that uses `@Bean` annotation
one function returns a void and i want the second one to return void as well.

but when i compile Spring boot and run my application i get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'reciveMessage' defined in class path resource [com/XXXXXX/Configuration/Configuration.class]: Invalid factory method 'reciveMessage': needs to have a non-void return type!
```

but i do not get any error message if i remove the second method , Spring boot process my first void method without any problem.

So my Question is why is this happening , why is it running my first void function and not my second void function.

is there a way for me to add more than one void function with `@Bean` annotation.

here are my code

```
package com.beanTester.start.beanTester;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;

@Configuration
 class configuration {

    private Logger logger;


    @Value("${logConfigPath}")
    private String path;

    private LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();

    @Bean
    public void logging_init() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
            manager.readConfiguration(inputStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            FileHandler logFile = new FileHandler("DefaultLogger.log");
            logFile.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            logger.setParent(Logger.getGlobal());
            logger.addHandler(logFile);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public String sendMessage() {
        return "I just send a message";
    }

    @Bean
    public void reciveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(" I recived a message called " + message);
    }

}
```

Comment: both functions failed to compile for me

Comment: The purpose of the `@Bean` annotation is to declare a bean, so what is the point of putting it to a void method ?

Comment: Why are you using `@Bean` on void methods? Those methods should add an object for your spring context.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder i'm just experimenting with spring-boot currently

Comment: Don't just post the methods, also the enclosing class is important (especially the type of class are those in `@Component` or `@Configuration` annotated classes).

Comment: @M.Deinum code added

Comment: But why did you put these `@Bean` annotations on these methods? They don't belong there. What do you think the `@Bean` annotation means?

Comment: @Jesper i'm just curious how come the void function get processed in one time and not in other, it's just a test, they are not code's for deployment

Comment: You're using the `@Bean` annotation in a way that it's not meant to be used. You'll get strange, random results that way. It doesn't make much sense to explain it - you're just using it the wrong way.

Comment: You might consider this a bug. `@Bean` factory methods which don't have any parameters are handled in a code path that doesn't check the return type. If you try to query for that bean from the context with `context.getBean("logging_init")`, it'll return a `NullBean`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes i think that's the reason , few tests without any parameter all returned `NullBean` and the Spring processed them without any error. Thank you